# Is appending user id to session id unsafe?

Tags: security, session, authentication, cryptography, sessionid

Lets say I have a cryptographically secure randomly generated string and I append a delimiter and the user's user id to that and use that as a session id. The use case is to prevent collisions. Is this going to make my system less secure than if I just used the randomly generated string?

Comment: I feel like this question would be better fitting for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the answer into two assumptions:

If you already send the user ID in some other manner (different field, different cookie, etc) and it would be visible to an attacker with access to the session ID then your approach does not add any attack surface to the implementation and the risk thus stays the same.

If the user ID would not otherwise be sent then you are providing an attacker with additional information which might be abused in other attacks. How dangerous this is depends on the importance of the user ID in your application.

Lastly, I am worried about your reasoning. If there is any reasonable mathematical chance of collision, then your sessionID is not long enough for the purpose you are trying to use it in. Err on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

If collisions are a risk, then your session identifier does not contain nearly entropy to be secure.

From [OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_ID_Entropy):

> If a session ID with an entropy of 64 bits is used, it will take an
> attacker at least 292 years to successfully guess a valid session ID,
> assuming the attacker can try 10,000 guesses per second with 100,000
> valid simultaneous sessions available in the web application

So if your session identifier could be successfully guessed without even trying, you have bigger problems. If the system itself generates identifiers that collide, then your source of entropy needs to be urgently reviewed.

To answer your question, the risk of introducing user ID is that if your session identifiers are ever leaked, an attacker can instantly identify the juicy ones. That is, those of administrators or root accounts. Also, as you are adding code to do this, the complexity of your application increases. Security is best when it is kept as simple as possible to address the risks faced by the application. And extra code means more attack surface, and the extra possibility of implementation vulnerabilities.

In summary, ensure that your session identifiers have an entropy of at least 64 bits and that the source of entropy is good (e.g. use a CSPRNG rather than a PRNG or use sources of entropy unique to your application).